# How do I block virtual machines from executing on Windows 7 or accessing the internet?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I want prevent virtual machines from executing in environments like VMWare or Virtual Box on Windows 7.  I know there are application blockers and application installation blockers that have password protected blacklists.  That is a possibility.  Another thought is to find software that prevents all virtualization.  Is there such a thing?  Otherwise, would it be possible to prevent any virtual machine from accessing the Internet?

Comment: So you don't want to use a group policy to prevent specific applications from being ran and you don't want to prevent applications from being installed, so what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

> I want prevent virtual machines from executing in environments like
>   VMWare or Virtual Box on Windows 7

Set strong password on administrator account and work only in standard account. This way virtual environment such as VirtualBox or VMware can't be installed if user of standard account don't know administrator's password. Again, to keep firewall settings locked you should forget a hobbit such as use administrator's account for regular/everyday work. If VM already installed and you want to restrict all VM's access to internet then in "advanced firewall settings" block outgoing traffic for VirtualBox or VMware. One more place to restrict access to internet is to disable network adapter in VM settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really prevent *all* virtualization. While modern virtualization software *takes advantage* of additional  features (which can be disabled), you can quite literally run a VM with no kernel hooks, a limited user account and internet access.

Arguably. QEMU is *emulation* but that's another story.

Some virtual machine software won't run *in* a vm, so convincing the VM host you're a VM might work, but this is *terribly* convoluted, and won't work since you can *nest* vms in vmware or virtualbox.

Its another piece of software. You can disable the drivers, uninstall it or not install it at all, but there's no magic, anti VM silver bullet

At the end of the day though, you're trying to find a convoluted technical solution to a simple social issue, much like this.

[image]

At the end of the day, all you need is a wrench to beat whoever installed a VM on your PC. Virtual machines don't spontaneously appear, and *explicitly* trying to block them feels a little like elephant repellent.

Comment: When you can configure a Windows machine to only allow specific applications to be started, it seems like a waste of time, trying to find a way to disable all virtualization.  You can block a VM from accessing the internet by secure network, only assign an ip address to machines you recognized, lock the switch/router configuration down. (random thoughts on the matter)

Comment: erm.  - for the latter part. Double nat. QEMU would work without it too. It apparently manages to get internet  *without* tap/tun drivers, or nat . I need to get an instance up to play with at some point.